# mysql table field values are hidden - why?

Tags: mysql

I am seeing this behavior on Windows 7 - mysql v5.6.17. When I try to view table records, the field with auto incrementing primary key (here it is the column with 'id') do not show values in all rows, but those values actually were populated after loading them from a data file. My initial thought was some of the values in ID column were missing, but they are not!

If I query individual row, then it shows the value in id column. Is this a normal behavior? Is there a better way to display table records?

Please see the image enclosed below.

[image]

Comment: Try: `SELECT id FROM pombe_,gene_deletion_library\G;`

Comment: I would like to display all columns with no hidden values, not just id column. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Try: `SELECT id, PlateNumber, Row, Col, Orf  FROM pombe_gene_deletion_library\G;`

Comment: It looks like corrupt data of some kind. Perhaps REPAIR can help!?!

Comment: @wchiquito: same display issue after applying your suggestion.

Comment: @Strawberry: data is not corrupted. Do you see similar behavior when data are corrupted?

Comment: @Strawberry I used check and repair commands on the table. Both checks out ok.

Comment: Do you have carriage returns or any other weird characters in your data?

Comment: @Strawberry: You are right. I had some carriage returns from the data file I loaded into my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data certainly appears corrupted.

An 'uncorrupted' result might look like this...

```
+----+-------------+-----+-----+-------+
| id | PlateNumber | Row | Col | Orf   |
+----+-------------+-----+-----+-------+
|  1 |           1 | A   |   1 | Empty |
|  2 | etc...      |     |     |       |
```